# Click Button to pass argument from fragment to another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, arguments

I am trying to make this but errors.

When I click a button and it executes function "showData()" ;
The reason I want to do this function because I want to change a fragment when
I click this button and also "pass the arguments" to the new fragment.
So it will keep executing function "passData()";

But it will get NullPointerException after 「editTextNAME.setText(restaurant.name); 」this line.

showData()

```
    public void showData(View view){
    RestaurantRepo repo = new RestaurantRepo(this);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> restaurantList =  repo.getRestaurantList();
    if ( restaurantList.size()!=0 ) {
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                restaurantID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.restaurantID);
                String idRestaurant = restaurantID.getText().toString();

                Bundle data = new Bundle();
                data.putString("restaurantID", idRestaurant); // argument

                Fragment fraUorD = null;
                fraUorD = new EditFragment_Fix_UorD();

                if ( null != fraUorD ) {
                    android.app.FragmentManager fragementManager = getFragmentManager();
                    android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragementManager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fraUorD);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                    passData(data); // when transaction done , execute passData() -> i want to pass argument when the new fragment come out
                }

            }
        });

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( MainActivity.this,restaurantList, R.layout.edit_fragment_fix_view,
                new String[] { "id","name","type","price","phone","addr"},
                new int[] {R.id.restaurantID, R.id.restaurantNAME,R.id.restaurantTYPE,
                        R.id.restaurantPRICE,R.id.restaurantPHONE,R.id.restaurantADDR});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    else
        Toast.makeText(this,"No restaurant!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // no data
```

passData()

```
   public void passData(Bundle data){

    int a = Integer.parseInt( data.getString("restaurantID", "")) ; // get it 

    Toast.makeText(this, ""+a,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    editTextNAME = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUpdateName);
    editTextTYPE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUpdateType);
    editTextPRICE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUpdatePrice);
    editTextPHONE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUpdatePhone);
    editTextADDR = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUpdateAddr);

    RestaurantRepo repo = new RestaurantRepo(this);
    Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant();
    restaurant = repo.getRestaurantById(a);

    // Everything is ok, but when executing codes below here will get errors 
    // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

    editTextNAME.setText(restaurant.name);
    editTextTYPE.setText(String.valueOf(restaurant.type));
    editTextPRICE.setText(String.valueOf(restaurant.price));
    editTextPHONE.setText(restaurant.phone);
    editTextADDR.setText(restaurant.addr);
}
```

Logcat here :

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.user.foody.MainActivity$override.passData(MainActivity.java:284)
                      at com.example.user.foody.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
                      at com.example.user.foody.MainActivity.passData(MainActivity.java:0)
                      at com.example.user.foody.MainActivity$2$override.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:244)
                      at com.example.user.foody.MainActivity$2$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
                      at com.example.user.foody.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:0)

Comment: In which layout file is `R.id.editTextUpdateName` defined? editTextNAME is null (i.e. cannot be found by findViewById).

Comment: @Jeremy i try to test that five codes , all of them are null ..  i don't know why
that really make me confused

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @Jeremy Never mind , don't worry :)  
Sorry, you mean which xml file i declared "editTextUpdateName"  or which java class i declared the "variable EditText editTextUpdateName" ?

Comment: You can't use communication between fragment to the another fragment , use communication with activities @Kevin . Google it how to do it

Comment: @KoVartthan Thank you. But I make a slide menu in my project and i make them change page by fragment , if i use to commnuicate with activity, my slide menu will disappear in my new page 
So that's why i want to do from fragment to fragment

Comment: @Kevin did you use bundle to pass the data ?

Comment: @KoVartthan Thank you!! I finallt know thay my thought is wrong
And now I am trying to debug them , thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot findviewbyId on fragment before onViewCreated.

I recommend reading this post about passing data through fragments.
http://gunhansancar.com/best-practice-to-instantiate-fragments-with-arguments-in-android/

important piece:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(...)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much bro !!

Comment: Hi, thank you so much , but now i have a little problem.
When I write down Fragment fragment = new Fragment().newInstance
This "newInstance method can be choose" but " can not be resolve"
Do you know why? Am i wrong?

Comment: Like this 
Fragment fraUorD = new EditFragment_Fix_UorD.newInstance
The newInstance method can not be resolve , but i already add it in my
EditFragment_Fix_UorD class

Comment: In my EditFragment_Fix_UorD class

   public static EditFragment_Fix_UorD newInstance( ... ) {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("NAME", editName);
         ...
        return fragment;
    }

Comment: you should call just EditFragment_Fix_UorD.newInstance(......)
WITHOUT the "new" keyword